# How to have a field conditional in Strapi's admin panel?

Tags: strapi

I'd like to show a field/component conditionally, in the admin panel.

**Example:** Let's say we have a simple enum field called "*Provider*". If the admin chooses *Provider A*, I'd like to show an extra field asking for more information. If *Provider B* is chosen, nothing is shown.

How can that be achieved in *Strapi v4.1.X*?

Comment: Hey @Sina, did you find answer to your question?

Comment: Hi @Nikita, unfortunately not. Has there been new releases covering this issue?